# Memory Leaks - Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, ios, memory-leaks

Can anyone see potential leaks in this code? I'm getting a "100%" leak according to Instruments on the line "NSString *ender = [temp stringFromDate:now];"

```
        NSDateFormatter* temp = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [temp setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSString *ender = [temp stringFromDate:now];

        DashboardViewController *controller = [[DashboardViewController alloc] init];
        [controller initWithStartDate:ender andEndDate:ender];
        [controller initAccount:account];

        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
        [temp release];
```

Comment: That really doesn't look like a leak to me. Have you tried to inline the now date? Otherwise, nothing I'd worry too much about, unless your app is really crashing with memory stuff here

Comment: what is "inline" and won't Apple reject the app if there are memory leaks?

Comment: Apple will not reject app for memory leaks, since they will not be able to detect them :) Of course, not in that case when your app will not feet into memory and hang.

Comment: they won't be able to detect them?!

Comment: Inline means that you don't declare the variable specifically, like so: NSString *ender = [temp stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
. But apple won't reject your app if it has memory leaks. It will reject the app if it crashes because of memory leaks tho. But the other posts below prob. answer the question better anyway :)

Comment: To answer to your other question: apple doesn't get to see the source code of your app. Sure, memory issues can be see by plain profiling, but only in bigger issues. What instruments does is a so called static code analysis. For that, you need the source code of the program. And apple doesn't get to see that

Comment: woah they don't see source code?!

Comment: Of course don't. You are sending compiled binary, signed with your certificate.

Comment: Can you include the entire list of leaks? since sometimes a leak creates a chain of leaks that all get listed by the instrument, so you may be not at the correct source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you pass your controller instance to the -presentModalViewController: method, that method will retain your controller. So you *can* safely release your controller, but you also *should* release your controller, since the memory management rules state that objects that you alloc+inited are owned by you and must be released.

On the other hand - just a small note - NSDateFormatter is a "heavy" object, cache the instance and reuse it, if it's possible. Probably this is also the reason why Apple deprecated this method. You might call -init on NSDateFormatter from iOS 2.0 till iOS 3.2, but it is deprecated after iOS 3.2 .

Comment: also i believe that there is something else around this code that might cause leaks .. could you add more details :) ?

Answer (score 4):

Do you release controller after all that stuff?

Comment: should I release the controller after presenting it? I haven't done this in any other presentModalViewController calls and they work fine.

Comment: it still causes a "100%" memory leak.

Comment: it says the responsbile frame is "NSDateFormatter"

Comment: Please update your code. And, what is 'account' variable, and do you release it?

Comment: Also, try to write [temp release] before presentModalViewController;

Comment: I figured it out. I retained startDate and endDate in my implementation of initStartDate! thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

This advice is unrelated to original question, but I think you should rename the `initWithStartDate:andEndDate:` and `initAccount:` methods since typically methods with "init" in the name return new instances.

Perhaps create your own `-(id)initWithStartDate:endDate:account:` and call the designated initializer from within.

Then you would create a new controller instance with

```
DashboardViewController *controller = [[DashboardViewController alloc] initWithStartDate:ender endDate:ender account:account];
```

Gonzalo